# RSA - Ecrypting the same data with the same public key = same ciphertext?

Tags: encryption, rsa

If an adversary knows my public key and guesses what was my plaintext, can he test for it somehow?

The most obvious way is encrypting the guessed plaintext with my public key and the same parameters that he can probably discover from the ciphertext, to see if the result is the same.

Comment: Would randomized padding have been used? $\:$

Comment: It is optional?! Isn't it the default when using crypto libraries?

Comment: No, ..., which is why I found the last part of your post strange. $\:$

Comment: @Ricky Demer, I think it is considered an important weakness in a cipher that an adversary can discover such thing from the ciphertext, so I guessed it should be somehow prevented by default (but i were not sure so I posted a question about it).

Comment: Can randomized padding completely prevent from such possibility?

Comment: I would certainly hope so. $\:$

Comment: See this too please: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34961/web-insecure-http-using-rsa-for-encrypting-passwords-on-the-client-side

Comment: Why aren't you using SSL/TLS there? $\:$

Comment: Also, the only reason I asked about padding was because the second sentence in your post here $\hspace{.42 in}$ made it sound like you had even less understanding of what to do than your post there does. $\:$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is "yes, RSA will encrypt the same cleartext to the same ciphertext every time." And yes, this is a known property of RSA. That's why every standard that uses RSA, such as PKCS or CMS, specifies the use of randomized padding.